# When iterating over a string, I am getting a character in my result that was never given

Tags: python, loops

Recently I have been working on making a Python program that iterates over a string. I'm making an ESOLANG with this, but I've run into a big issue.
**This question is quite long, and I apologize for this.**
Here is the basic syntax, which you'll need to know to answer this.

- Current Value is a single character stored as ascii numbers.
- `e` sets the current value to the next character, so `eA` sets current value to `A` and `eB` sets it to `B`.
- `p` prints the current value, so `eFpeopp` prints `Foo`.
- `v` sets a variable. Running `eAvB` will set the variable `B` to `A`.
- `g` gets the value for a variable. The interpolator comes with a default variable (`?`) which returns the version. So `evpg?p` will print `v2`. Use `gc` to get the variable with the same name as the current value.
- `(` starts a loop and `)` ends a loop. You can specify the amount of times the loop will run with `(n)` with n as the number from 0-9. You can use a bigger number with `c` which will use the current value (ascii number)
- `+` and `-` increase and decrease the current value.
- `f` generates a factorial. The variable `0` will be set to the length of the output, so `5` will make `0` to `3` because the factorial of `5` is `120` which is `3` digits. Then variables `1`-`3` will have the results because there are three letters. So this program sets current value to 5 and prints the factorial of it. `+++++fg1pg2pg3p`. In this example, the length (3) is hard coded, so another number wont work. Another flaw is that input is only 1 number. This can be fixed with loops.
  There are some other characters, but they are not related to this. If you are interested, you can use [this Discord bot](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=872128065323548783&scope=bot).
  Now, my problem. I am trying to get the factorial working, but I can't get it to work. This is my code (yes it is very long):

```py
from math import factorial
def parse(code, currentValue=0, varis={"?":"2"}, getCurrent=False):
    # Copyright (c) UCYT5040
    # minlang - A minimal language
    output = ""
    outputNext = False
    getNext = False
    setNext = False
    valNext = False
    appendNext = False
    getLoopAmount = False
    inLoop = False
    loopCode = ""
    runMoreTimes = 0
    openLoops = 0
    for i in code:
        if valNext:
            currentValue = ord(i)
            valNext = False
            continue
        if appendNext:
            currentValue += ord(i)
            appendNext = False
            continue
        if getNext:
            if i == "c":
                currentValue = ord(varis[chr(currentValue)])
            else:
                currentValue = ord(varis[i])
            getNext = False
            continue
        if outputNext:
            output += chr(i)
            outputNext = False
            continue
        if setNext:
            varis[i] = chr(currentValue)
            setNext = False
            continue
        dontDoThis = False
        if inLoop:
            if i == "(": openLoops+=1
            if i == ")" and openLoops != 0:
                openLoops -= 1
            if openLoops == 0:
                inLoop = False
                dontDoThis = True
            if not dontDoThis:
                loopCode += i
                continue
        if getLoopAmount:
            if i == "c": runMoreTimes = currentValue
            else: runMoreTimes = int(i)
            getLoopAmount = False
            inLoop = True
        while runMoreTimes > 0:
            if not inLoop:
                runMoreTimes -= 1
                output += parse(loopCode, currentValue, varis)
                currentValue = parse(loopCode, currentValue, varis, getCurrent=True)
            else: break
        if runMoreTimes == 0 and not inLoop:
            loopCode = ""

        if i == "e": # Sets the current value to the next character
            valNext = True
        if i == "a": # Adds the next character to the current value
            appendNext = True
        if i == "p": # Print current value
            output += chr(currentValue)
        if i == "g": # Get the value of a variable
            getNext = True
        if i == "v": # Set a variable
            setNext = True
        if i == "(":
            getLoopAmount = True
            openLoops += 1
        if i == "-":
            currentValue -= 1
        if i == "+":
            currentValue += 1
        if i == "i":
            currentValue = ord(input("Enter only 1 character of input: "))
        if i == "?":
            if varis["%"] == varis["!"]:
                output += chr(currentValue)
        if i == "&":
            if not varis["%"] == varis["!"]:
                break
        if i == "f":
            fact = str(factorial(currentValue))
            varis["0"] = str(len(fact))
            for ii in range(len(fact)):
                f = fact[ii]
                print(type(f),f,"fact")
                varis[str(ii+1)] = f
            print(varis["0"])
    if getCurrent:
        return currentValue
    return output
print(parse(input("Enter code to run: ")))
```

Here are a few of my attempts to get it working.

```
UCYT5040: min run +++++fg1pg2pg3p 
BOT > Minlang Runner: 120
```

This was successful, but the following are not.

```
UCYT5040: min run va++++f g0(cga+vagcp)
Command raised an exception: KeyError: '\x01'
Expanation: Set var a to 0. Get the factorial of 4. Get the value of 0, and run a loop of its length. Edit var a to get each digit. Get the value of the 1st digit (var 1). --ERROR: Trying to get var \x01 rather than 1.--
```

Why is \x01 passed?

Comment: Does your testing environment not identify the line that raised the exception?

Comment: need provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to troubleshoot

Comment: @DavisHerring that is why they provided an explanation

Comment: @SamarthBhatia: This algorithm hardly depends on Discord—so if that environment is so hostile to debugging the first step is to make an independent implementation (and maybe eventually ask Stack Overflow about *that*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace `chr()` and `ord()` with the simple `str()` and `int()` in the `getNext` function's `if` branch, i.e.,

> `currentValue = ord(varis[chr(currentValue)])`

Why:
using `currentValue = 1` and assuming factorial has been calculated

`chr(1) = '\x01'` so when you try to access `varis['\x01']` the key doesn't exist in the dictionary [since inside the factorial you store it using `str(ii+1)...` not `chr()`

Instead,
`str(1) = '1'`, so you will access `varis['1']`, which will result in `'2'` and `int('2') = 2`.